# t-sql: update in specific order determined by 'in' expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose:

```
declare @counter int
set @counter = 0

update MyTable
set @counter = MyField = @counter + 1
where Some_ID in (select ID from SomeTable)
```

What I want is that update happened in same order as `select ID from SomeTable` IDs are returned. Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Gotta ask... why?  Order shouldn't be important in set operations.

Comment: You can do this using a CTE and ROW_NUMBER, in a single statement.

Comment: @AustinSalonen it's just that `select ID from SomeTable` comes to me as a parameter I can't change and in a specific order and I need `MyField` to store that order information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`... you determine the order that you want the records from `SomeTable` returned in the `OVER` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
;WITH rn (ID, rowNumber) AS
(
    SELECT st.ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY st.ID)
    FROM SomeTable st
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE mt.Some_ID = st.ID
    )   
)
UPDATE mt
SET MyField = rowNumber
FROM 
    MyTable mt 
    JOIN rn ON rn.ID = mt.Some_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to have a column containing an incrementing number in the updated records I think the only way you could do this is to get the list of IDs and do a number of updates.

In SQL server you would likely do this using a cursor.

```
DECLARE @id int, @counter int
SET @counter = 0
DECLARE ids CURSOR
  FOR SELECT ID FROM SomeTable

OPEN ids
FETCH NEXT FROM ids INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS == 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = @counter WHERE Some_ID = @id
  SET @counter = @counter + 1
  FETCH NEXT FROM ids INTO @id
END

CLOSE ids
DEALLOCATE ids
```

Comment: yeap, but I hope there is a declarative way